# specific media query not overriding?

Tags: css, resize, media-queries

So I have an element that I want to change at  750px  and  500px:

```
.footer-logo img {
 content:url(...);
 }
```

and then:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.footer-logo img{
margin-top: -58px !important;
padding:64px;
}
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.footer-logo img {
width: 80vw !important;
max-width:none !important;
margin-top:-10px !important;
}
```

The 500px changes happen but the changes when testing at 700px do not happen. I know I shouldn't be using !important so much but the styling just won't happen without it... Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can try add 500px Changing meadia after add 700px meadia query.

Comment: can you provide the code snippet for what that would look like?

Comment: I put the Answer please Check it.i think it is work.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This. please check div Color changes According to media query
HTML

```
<div class="footer-logo">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/000/fff&text=Throbble!">
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.footer-logo > img{
margin-top: -58px !important;
padding:64px;
}

.footer-logo {
  background-color:yellow;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.footer-logo > img {
width: 80px !important;
max-width:none !important;
margin-top:-10px !important;

}
.footer-logo {
  background-color:red;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me identify that my media query size should have been 700px and 400px!